# $match on sum of two fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

In the mongodb aggregation pipeline how do I match on the sum of two fields being non zero? So I can say the following to give me all the documents where startPos is greater than 10

```
db.strategy.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
             "startPos": {"$gt" :10}
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

But how do I say something like:

```
db.strategy.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
             {"$subtract":["endPos","startPos"]}: {"$gt" :10} <== Clearly not legal
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

Comment: `$redact` is the right operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `redact` to achieve this.

```
db.strategy.aggregate([
                {"$redact" : 
                    { "$cond" : { 
                        if : { $gt: [ {"$subtract":["$endPos","$startPos"] }, 10] }, 
                        then: "$$KEEP", 
                        else: "$$PRUNE" 
                        } 
                    }         
                }
            ] );
```